# Render only when i set it to render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, ruby-on-rails-5, partials

so my question is how can i enable this piece of code only when i want? I have multiple pages and some pages i need to remove that piece of code.

**This is my current partial _navbar.html.erb and div.spotlight is the piece of code i need to disable in some pages**

```
<div class="container">
  <nav class="logonav">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col50"><span class="logo"></span>
        <h2>Musicus</h2>
        <p>De ti para o mundo</p>
      </div>
      <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <div class="col50">
            <%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, class: 'ui-btn btn-normal', method: :delete %>
          </div>
      <% else %>
          <div class="col50">
            <%= link_to new_user_registration_path, class: 'ui-btn btn-accent' do %>
                <span class="icon-add-user"></span> Criar Conta
            <% end %>
            <%= link_to new_user_session_path, class: 'ui-btn btn-normal' do %>
                <span class="icon-login"></span> Login
            <% end %>
          </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="spotlight">
    <%= yield :other_message %>
    <%= render 'search' %>
    <%= yield :primary_message %>
  </div>

  <%= yield :other_nav %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple `if` statement:

```
<% if show_spotlight %>
  <div class="spotlight">
    <%= yield :other_message %>
    <%= render 'search' %>
    <%= yield :primary_message %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: An instance variable? :/ im kinda new using rails

Comment: Any variable is fine, whatever you use to determine if the div.spotlight should show or night.